# Create Complex Object WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Role Entity Of My Project has Multiple Action With This Modeling:

```
{
    public string Uid { get; set; }
    public string Descript { get; set; }
    public bool Premitive { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ActionDto> Actions { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

I use UnitOfWork Repository Pattern
The create method is:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create([FromBody] RoleFullDto dto)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dto.Actions == null || dto.Actions.Count <= 0)
                return BadRequest();

            //If I Pass Only action uid, return EntityModelException
            //When I Pass Complete Entity, Create New Action
            //foreach (var action in dto.Actions)
            //{
                //var act = UnitOfWork.ActionRepository.Get(action.Uid);
                //action.ActionName = act.ActionName;
                //action.MenuId = act.MenuId;
                //action.PersianActionName = act.PersianActionName;
            //}

            var role = ModelFactory.GetRole(dto);
            if (role == null)
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, dto);



            var result = await this.AppRoleManager.CreateAsync(role);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return GetErrorResult(result);
            }
            return ActionResult<Role>(role, null, "CreateRole", HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }
```

I pass this parameters To create new role:

```
{
   Name: "TestRole1",
   Descript: "This is Test",
   Premitive: false,
   Actions: [{uid:1},{uid:2},{uid:3}]
}
```

but this method wand to add 3 new Action that Exist in Databese
How Can I Create Role With Exist Actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are passing entities that doesn't come from the db, Entity Framework tries to create them. You could use the Attach method of DBSet to link you action objects to entities. But since you're not using a DBSet directly you could also do something like this :

```
dto.Actions = dto.Actions.Select(a => UnitOfWork.ActionRepository.Get(a.Uid)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, I Change The Code and use this code:                       role.Actions = dto.Actions.Select(a => UnitOfWork.ActionRepository.Get(a.Uid)).ToList();                                      in this time return this Error: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Comment: I think you might have the same action multiple times in the Action list of the role. Is it the case? Is it supposed to happen?